# multiple definitions of a dynamic array declared globally in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

I want to have a dynamic array declared globally which is initialized in
main and then to use the values in another functions which are also included in main, but I got this error "multiple definitions of.."because I included the file with global variables: "variabile.globale.h" in main and also in "functions.h", but if I don't do that the values  will not be 
recognized in both files.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

#include "variabile_globale.h"

#include "functions.h"

using namespace std;

int N = 4;
double suma;
double produsul;

int main()
{
int i;
for (i = 1; i <= N; i++)
{
pos_x[i] = i;
cout << "x="<<pos_x[i] << endl;
sum(i);
product(i);
}


return 0;

delete [] pos_x;
}
```

Global variable file:

variabile_globale.h

```
 extern  int N;
 extern double *pos_x = new double [N];
 extern double suma;
 extern double produsul;
```

And functions.h

```
#ifndef FUNCTIONS_H_INCLUDED
#define FUNCTIONS_H_INCLUDED

void sum(int i);
void product(int i);

#endif
```

function.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>

#include"variabile_globale.h"

void sum(int i)
{
suma = 0;
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
suma = suma + pos_x[i];

}

}

void product(int i)

{
 produsul = 1;
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
 produsul =  produsul*pos_x[i];

 }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Use std::vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
extern double *pos_x = new double [N];
```

A declaration that has an initializer is a definition. So this line defines `pos_x` in every file that includes this header.

Change the declaration to actually be a declaration:

```
extern double *pos_x;
```

and define `pos_x` in exactly one source file.